# mechanics problem: rope on a fictionless table through a hole

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

The problem is from "An introduction to Mechanics" by Daniel Kleppner and Robert Kolenkow. The book has a second edition, and the problem is not changed. The number of the problem is 4.16 in second edition.

> A rope of mass $M$ and length $l$ lies on a frictionless table, with a
> short portion $l_0$ , hanging through a hole. Initially the rope is at
> rest.
>
> (a) Find a general equation for $x(t)$, the length of rope through the
> hole.
>
> (b) Find the particular solution so that the initial conditions
> are satisfied.

The answer given by the author is

$x = A{e^{\gamma t}} + B{e^{ - \gamma t}}$

But I can't agree with it.

At first, I didn't understand why this problem is not relevant to the way that the rope piled on the table. I thought different way of piling(a lump or a straight line) should affect the result.

Then I figure out the important role played by the hole in this problem. During the movement of the rope, horizontal momentum of the rope near the hole is not only affected by the pulling of hanging rope but also affected by the hole. If the rope is hanging on the edge of the table, the rope should not be able to make a drastic 90 degree turn. Fortunately, we need not worry about the horizontal motion of the rope, thus the piling situation is not relevant to the problem.

The differential equation I figure out is

$\rho gx = \frac{{d\left( {\rho x\dot x} \right)}}{{dt}}$

this is equivalent to

$gx = {{\dot x}^2} + \ddot x$

This differentiation definitely can't give the answer provided by the author.

And if the initial condition is $l_0=0$, then we can have a simple answer:

$x = \frac{1}{6}g{t^2}$

as discussed here https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/rope-through-a-hole-in-a-frictionless-table.781299/

But if ${l_0} \ne 0$, there is no simple solution!!!

There is also discussion here which seems to give the "right answer" provided by author https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/rope-through-a-hole.707735/. But I can't agree with the way of application of Newton's second law, since they neglect the role played by the hole in stopping the horizontal motion of the rope.

So can somebody give some comment on this problem? Am I right or wrong?

Comment: I think your D.E. is missing the acceleration of the part of the rope which is on the table. Even if there's no friction, it does need to be accelerated. And then you're correct that the way it is piled will be of importance -- but assuming it to be straight will make sense I guess. Let me say that I don't think much of the problem...

Comment: Your last question is asking for an opinion, which is considered off-topic here, so I've removed it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the author has forgotten to mention that the part of the rope on the table is stretched out in a straight line, otherwise, I would say the way it's piled does make a difference, and the problem is not solvable as stated.

In that case, the equation of motion is simply

$$M \ddot x = m_{hang} g$$

$$M \ddot x = M \frac x l g$$

$$\ddot x = \frac g l x$$

This indeed gives us a general solution of

$$x(t) = A e^{\lambda t} + B e^{-\lambda t}$$

where $\lambda = \sqrt{\frac x l}$